# HAML: Indenting if/else statements with common content

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following in my view:

```
- if (condition)
  %div.truecondition
    (Ten lines of content)
- else
  %div.falsecondition
    (Ten lines of the same content)
```

I'd like to factor out the ten lines of content to go below the if/else statement...but if I do that, indentation means the content won't be nested inside the div specified in the if/else. I'm sure this is a common problem, I'm just wondering what the solution is. So...how do I factor out that ten lines while keeping the content nested in the .truecondition/.falsecondition div?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can try [Ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
%div{ :class => condition ? 'truecondition' : 'falsecondition' }
  (Ten lines of content)
```

Answer (score 2):

JCorcuera's answer is better, but this is dirtier:

```
%div(class="#{!!condition}condition")
  (Ten lines of content)
```

Assuming you literally have css classes named `truecondition` and `falsecondition`, which as I type this seems unlikely.