# haml two spaces issue

Tags: haml

When using haml I have following problem.

First I want to check one variable and after that render something else, but it still should be nested.

Let me explain

code:

```
.a
  .b

gives:   <div class=a><div class=b></div></div>
```

When I use haml if else, I can't nest .b inside .a:

```
- if id == 3
  .a{style => 'xxx'}
- else
  .a{style => 'yyy'}

    .b <-- 2 spaces, otherwise it fails. but 2 spaces are causing the following issue:
```

The problem is, because there is no end in haml, I don't know how to put .b within .a div, in both situations (if id ==3, or else).

As an real live example:

```
- if home != nil
  .home
    home.id
- else
  .home
    empty
- end   <--- can't use
  - if room != nil <-- without end, this will be executed only if home == nil but I wan't this to be executed always
    room.id
  - else
    empty
```

because haml doens't support -end, I can't use it. If I don't use it, haml automatically closes  div if I start to cehck 'room's values because these are in the same line :)

Example with comparing variable to nil, or doing something only if the variable is nil is just an example. I'm looking for a solution that solves such problem with  indenting after else so it applies to the whole statement.

There are similar question: [HAML: Indenting if/else statements with common content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147610/haml-indenting-if-else-statements-with-common-content)

So, in your case you would do like:

```
.a{ :style => id == 3 ? 'xxx' : 'yyy' }
  .b
```

*edited*:
In case of `if... elsif... elsif...` you can write your own helper:

```
.a{ :style => select_style(variable) }
  .b

#helper method
def select_style(val)
  case val
  when "3"
    "xxx"
  when "4"
    "yyy"
  else
  "zzz"
  end
end
```

Of course you can write it all in haml, but it will be ugly:

```
- if id == "3" then val="xxx"
- elsif id == "4" then val="yyy"
- else val="zzz"
.a { :style => val }
 .b
```

HAML has its advantages, but it is an example of one of the disadvantages.

*edited*

Or you can going mad and do like:

```
.a{:style => if var == "3" then "xxx" elsif var == "4" then "yyy" else "zzz" end}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar question: [HAML: Indenting if/else statements with common content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147610/haml-indenting-if-else-statements-with-common-content)

So, in your case you would do like:

```
.a{ :style => id == 3 ? 'xxx' : 'yyy' }
  .b
```

*edited*:
In case of `if... elsif... elsif...` you can write your own helper:

```
.a{ :style => select_style(variable) }
  .b

#helper method
def select_style(val)
  case val
  when "3"
    "xxx"
  when "4"
    "yyy"
  else
  "zzz"
  end
end
```

Of course you can write it all in haml, but it will be ugly:

```
- if id == "3" then val="xxx"
- elsif id == "4" then val="yyy"
- else val="zzz"
.a { :style => val }
 .b
```

HAML has its advantages, but it is an example of one of the disadvantages.

*edited*

Or you can going mad and do like:

```
.a{:style => if var == "3" then "xxx" elsif var == "4" then "yyy" else "zzz" end}
```

Comment: what if I have if, elsif x 10 ?

Comment: sure this helps, but not in this situation.

what I really have is, if special variable exists, show one div. if it doesnt, show another with values:

- if @user.id == '1'
  .mydivname
- else
  .mydivname{:id => @street.name}

after that I want to have another div within .mydivname:

  .anotherdiv

Comment: Why you can't use `.mydivname{:id => @user.id == "1" ? "" : @street.name }` ?

Comment: because after that div I have another div that should be inside :) I will send complete code so that explains the problem

Comment: I have updated my question. the link that you've pasted solves problem when I'd like to change first line, but I'd like to change some content afterwards

Comment: Thank you. I have used the mentioned link and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this:

```
- if contition
  - attrs = { class: '..', id: '..' }
- else
  - attrs = { style: '...' }

.a{attrs}
  .b
```