# Haml to Html, how to assign the right value to a parent tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to web dev. Below i have a code in haml

```
%th
    %a#title_header
        %a{:th => ("hilite" if @sort == "title")}= link_to 'Movie Title', :sort => "title"
```

which gives me the following HTML

```
<th>
   <a id='title_header'>
       <a th='hilite'><a href="/movies?sort=title">Movie Title</a></a>
   </a>
</th>
```

While what i am looking to get is

```
<th class='hilite'>
    <a id='title_header'><a href="/movies?sort=title">Movie Title</a></a>
</th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar question with my answer: [Adding dynamic attributes to HAML tag using helper method in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902377/adding-dynamic-attributes-to-haml-tag-using-helper-method-in-rails/10908734#10908734)

In your case it should be like:

```
%th{:class => if @sort == 'title' then 'hilite' end}
    %a#title_header
        %a= link_to 'Movie Title', :sort => "title
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%th.hilite
  %a#title_header
    %a{:href => "/movies?sort=title"} Movie Title
```

by the way there's a project called http://html2haml.heroku.com/ check it out !