# HAML class string with class based on if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have this HAML code adding an "active" class based on an if statement.

```
= link_to 'Contact Information',
  edit_account_path(:contact_information),
  class: ("active" if params[:section] == 'contact_information')
```

I want to also add a string of classes permanently, outside of the if statement.

Something like

```
= link_to 'Contact Information',
  edit_account_path(:contact_information),
  class: "Tab large", ("active" if params[:section] == 'contact_information')
```

I need to do this without creating a helper method because I'm not allowed to edit the code too much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding dynamic attributes to HAML tag using helper method in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902377/adding-dynamic-attributes-to-haml-tag-using-helper-method-in-rails)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`ternary operator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation):

```
= link_to 'Contact Information',
  edit_account_path(:contact_information),
  class: "Tab large #{params[:section] == 'contact_information' ? 'active' : ''}"
```

The second example:

```
= link_to 'Contact Information',
  edit_account_path(:contact_information),
  class: current_page?(edit_user_registration_path) ? 'active' : ''
```

Comment: now that's a bit clumsy, seeking answers here is a way to understand the concept/way of doing things and not ask to just complete your work. the logic is quite self explanatory in the first example itself.

Comment: Gotcha! I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

create a helper method say find_classes,

```
def find_classes(section)
  default_class = ['Tab Large']
  if section == 'contact_information'
    default_class << 'active'
  end
  default_class.join(' ')
end
```

and from your view,

```
class: find_classes(params[:section])
```

Advantage:
you can have multiple `if`'s and can have various classes appended.